# looking for the inverse of matrix that has to be use RREF, and also it needs to be in modulo 5, is there a more straight forward way to do this?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

[image]

Trying to do it step by step with RREF operations but I'm not making any progress, is there any more straight forward way to do this?

Comment: How are you doing this "step by step"?

Comment: Making the original matrix on the left side and identity matrix on the right side and do RREF left and right at the same time.

Comment: Can you write up your work in the question?

Comment: But I don't know how to approach this...

Comment: This matrix appears to be singular over $\mathbb Z_5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb Z_5$, it holds $2\cdot 3=1$ and $4\cdot 4=1$. Using this information, you can divide by any number, and proceed with the usual algorithm.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but how can I know only with doing RREF?